# Help to draw arrows with tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, axis

i don't know how to do can someone help me to draw this using tikz

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Have you done any research? I would recommend going through the first tutorial (chapter 2) in the TikZ manual (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), that should teach you what need to draw something like that, I think.

Comment: Please your own Tikz code before asking how to draw something in Tikz.  If you haven't tried to do it, then that's not good.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. i don't find like this in chapter 2, can just tel me how i can start .

Comment: No, you won't find how to draw *exactly* that, but you will find instructions on how to draw a line or an arrow from one point to another, and also instructions on how to add text. And that is all your diagram consists of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a starting point.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{>=stealth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0:0) -- (0:4) node[above] {axe de $s$};
\draw[->] (0:0) -- (45:4) node[right] {axe de $s'$};
\draw[->] (0:0) -- (-20:2) node[right] {$u$};
\draw[->] (0:0) -- (20:2) node[right] {$s(u)$};
\draw[->] (0:0) -- (70:2) node[left] {$s'(s(u))=\rho(u)$};
\draw[-] (-20:2) -- (20:2) -- (70:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]